# Java - create new directory with mkdir()?

Tags: java, path, directory

I have this:

```
  File newFileJPG = new File("resized_pictures/");
         if(folder.isDirectory() && !newFileJPG.exists()){
              newFileJPG.mkdir();
  }
```

why mkdir() is make this file

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/czmyg.jpg]

, no folder? And how can make folder?

Comment: You can create the directories using `Files.createDirectories(yourPath);`.

Comment: but i use newFileJPG  that after this code   ImageIO.write(tempJPG, "jpg", newFileJPG);